# How to insert data in map from a text file in java

Tags: java

I have a file `data.txt` which contains only 2 strings each line and they are not equally spaced . How to read that data from the file and insert into a map quickly. The format of `data.txt`

```
satisfactory 3
worth        5
wow 5
terrible      1
nice   5
good     6
awesome 8
fabulous 9
fantastic     10
```

How to extract the data per line and insert it in a map `Map<String,Integer>`
I tried using `StringTokenizer` but due to variable space between `string` and `integer` value it did not work well. Please help

Comment: Read the whole line and split it using `"\\s+"` or use it in `Scanner` as the delimiter or somewhere else. Btw: if you have a question and you have some code, then it is always a good idea to post that code with an explanation about that expected and the actual result.

Comment: Well, it is not a trick, just a regular expression :D.

Comment: @Tom my apologies. I couldn't think of it.

Comment: @Tom - Should add it as an answer. Get some more of that reputation points :-)

Comment: @Tom I wanted the concept about how to do it and I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two (and many more :D) possible ways doing that by using the `Scanner` class and the regular expression `\\s+`. [This expression matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef) any amount of white spaces if there is at least one.

Version one, using `String#split`:

```
try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"))) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String line = scanner.nextLine();
        final String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
        map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
}
```

Version two, using the regular expression as the delimiter in `Scanner` (mind that this version has  a problem if a line contains more than two elements, like `"a   b   c"`):

```
try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"))) {
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\s+");
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String key = scanner.next();
        final String value = scanner.next();
        map.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "satisfactory 3\n"
            + "worth        5\n"
            + "wow 5\n"
            + "terrible      1\n"
            + "nice   5\n"
            + "good     6\n"
            + "awesome 8\n"
            + "fabulous 9\n"
            + "fantastic     10";

    Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
    String[] lines = input.split("\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] stringNumber = line.split("[ ]+");
        m.put(stringNumber[0], Integer.parseInt(stringNumber[1]));
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entrySet : m.entrySet()) {
        String key = entrySet.getKey();
        Integer value = entrySet.getValue();
        System.out.format("%s -> %s\n", key, value);
    }
}
```

The result:

> awesome -> 8
>   fantastic -> 10
>   satisfactory -> 3
>   good -> 6
>   fabulous -> 9
>   wow -> 5
>   terrible -> 1
>   nice -> 5
>   worth -> 5